# Is key 0 the same as null and how do I prevent it from crashing?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, dictionary, key, firebase-analytics

I have two `variables` of type `NSMutableDictionary` in a function. The function works fine but `firebase-analytics` show that it does crash on occasions.

In `debug-mode` the values of one of the variables is `0 key/value pairs`. Does this mean that it is completely without value and therefore is `nil`? If so, how do I check whether it's nil to prevent it from crashing?

Here's the function:

```
-(void)setPerson:(NSMutableDictionary*)newPerson{
    if (thisPerson != newPerson) {

    thisPerson = newPerson;

    //It Crashes Here In The NSLog... sometimes
    NSLog(@"currentPerson: %@",newCurrentPerson);
}
```

So, `thisPerson` is expressivly nil at first, and `newPerson` is `0 key/value pair`. Then `thisPerson` is assigned the `key 0/value pair` value as well. And sometimes it crashes in the `NSLog`. Very confusing.

Comment: That is not the complete function. You are missing at least a `}` to close the `if` statement. Also I don't see any assignment of `newCurrentPerson`.

Comment: You should also specify just want `thisPerson` and `newCurrentPerson` are. Are they parts of your class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. > In debug-mode the values of one of the variables is 0 key/value pairs.
   >   Does this mean that it is completely without value and therefore is
   >   nil?

No. It means, that variable contains dictionary object that completely without value and therefore it is NOT `nil`. It is empty `NSMutableDictionary *` (or may be `NSDictionary *` if there some error out of this function).

2. > If so, how do I check whether it's nil to prevent it from crashing?

To check if variable is nil in Objective C you should simply do:

```
if (newPerson == nil) {
    // do something with nil case
}
```

But it is probably not that you need.

3. More about `nil`:

```
    //It Crashes Here In The NSLog... sometimes
    NSLog(@"currentPerson: %@",newCurrentPerson);
```

If you have implicit assumption that `NSLog(@"currentPerson: %@",nil);` cause crash - then it is wrong. `NSLog` handles `nil` perfectly fine in such case.

4. So I believe that problem somewhere out of code you posted in question.